# Forcing multcomp:glht() to calculate as many meaningful pairwise factor combination as possible

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I have a very imbalanced dataset consisting of several habitats (i.e. "woodland", "grassland", "swamp", and so on) with different sample sizes (10 - 40) and species counts as outcome. Species counts are not always normally distributed. I want to test if there are significant differences between different habitats for each of the observed species.

I was taught that `glht()` from the package multcomp is suited for my type of data, so i am running a basic:

```
  library(multcomp)
  library(sandwich)
  res1 <- aov(Counts ~ Habitat, data=data)
  res2 <- glht(res1, mcp(Habitat = "Tukey"), vcov = vcovHC)
```

in a loop for all my ~20 species.

As it turned out, some of my species are not present in all of the habitats, and i guess this is why i get the following error for the first of these species:

```
Error in if (!chkcorr(corr)) stop(sQuote("corr"), " is not a correlation matrix") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In RET$pfunction("adjusted", ...) : Completion with error > abseps
    2: In RET$pfunction("adjusted", ...) : Completion with error > abseps
3: In RET$pfunction("adjusted", ...) : Completion with error > abseps
4: In sqrt(diag(covm)) : NaNs produced
5: In sqrt(1/diag(V)) : NaNs produced
6: In cov2cor(covm) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
```

If that is true, is there a way to tell `glht()` to run through every meaningful pairwise test, and to ignore combinations that make no sense to test?